# In java eclipse, i retrieved data from the database and pasted in the already present excel. The data already present is getting deleted

Tags: java, apache-poi

In java eclipse, I ran a query to retrieve data from the database and pasted in the already present excel sheet (exceldatabase16) in the C drive. Already present excel -exceldatabase16 contains column names in the first row. And the data pasted into the exceldatabase16 is pasted from row 6 and column F. Still the row 1 data is getting deleted.

```
public static  void retrieveData1( Connection connection) throws SQLException, IOException 
    {
         Statement stmt = null;
           ResultSet rs = null;
         stmt = connection.createStatement();


         rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM countries where region_id='3' ");
//         getColumnNames(rs);


         XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
         XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("countriesdetails");
         XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(5);
         XSSFCell cell;
         cell = row.createCell(5);

         cell.setCellValue("country id");
         cell = row.createCell(6);
         cell.setCellValue("country name");
         cell = row.createCell(7);
         cell.setCellValue("region");

         int i = 6;

         while(rs.next()) {
            row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
            cell = row.createCell(5);      
            cell.setCellValue(rs.getString(1));

            cell = row.createCell(6);
            cell.setCellValue(rs.getString(2));
            cell = row.createCell(7);
            cell.setCellValue(rs.getInt(3));

            i++;
         }

         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\workspace\\ApachePoi\\exceldatabase16.xlsx"));
         workbook.write(out);
         out.close();
         workbook.close();
         System.out.println("exceldatabase.xlsx written successfully");     
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are overwriting your existing file with a new one whenever you run this program.

According to the XSSF documentation, there is a method signature of the XSSFWorkbook creation which can open an existing file instead of making a new one.

Try something along the lines of:

```
 XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\workspace\\ApachePoi\\exceldatabase16.xlsx"));
```